# What do you call a layout of non-regular non-overlapping tiles?

Tags: interaction-design, terminology, interface

Some interfaces present the user with a collection of non-overlapping tiles of different sizes. For example:

[image: Ubuntu phone interface]

Similar layouts include Pinterest and Windows 8 / Xbox, but looking at screenshots these are more regular - they seem to define global columns or rows but there are none enforced in my visual example above. I'm thinking more [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co) than [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) (unless the same term applies to both and it's just a matter of degree).

Is there in fact a name for this layout?

Comment: I refer to this as "masonry" but I think that's based on the JavaScript library and not necessarily a widespread name for the pattern.

Comment: @MattObee what about "cascading grid layout"?

Comment: Thanks to Google + I want to call it ["cards"](http://insideintercom.io/why-cards-are-the-future-of-the-web/) but that's not quite right. It's certainly a rising trend, and it's well beyond the point where it can be called just "pinterest like"

Comment: @BenBrocka yes, I think cards are often the widget involved, but it doesn't capture simply the layout (cause cards could be laid out in a regular grid) - but great link!

Answer (score 1):

I've not specifically heard it used for UI but I think the word to describe it is "tesselated":

- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) (includes many forms of tessellation/tiling)
- [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tessellate&tbm=isch)

If someone said a UI was using "tesselated irregular tiles", I'd understand a Win8/Flickr photostream/Pinterest type layout.

Comment: tessellation is definitely too regular for what I'm thinking of, but thanks - I'm aware my question could do with a visual example, and as soon as I have one I will post one

Comment: My understanding of tesselation was that regularity/repetition isn't a nessesity but rather the most common form. See the Voronoi tiling example at the bottom of the wikipedia page. (This doesn't mean you're wrong or I'm right - if most people understand tesselation to be regular then it's not the right word.)

Answer (score 0):

**Mosaic Interface**

Since "tiled" implies regularity, I'd call that a "mosaic" interface to include tiles of various sizes/orientations.

Answer (score -1):

Isogonal (regular/irregular) tiling.

Comment: This seems visually similar but I've never seen the term applied to a UI.

Comment: The wikipedia explanation of isogonal figures was a bit mind-numbing. There's a screenshot labelled isogonal in the Tesselation article that looks right, but nothing in the isogonal article seems right. Can you provide any direct examples, explanations. FWIW I don't mind a mathematical/geometric term - if the hat fits...